# Adding an empty row to databound combobox Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, row

I know this question has been asked a thousand times, I have done my research but I am unable to find anything that actually fixes this issue for me.  I am loading a combobox from a datatable, and setting the .selectedindex=-1 so that the user can make a selection. But if user changes their mind and wants to unselect it, they cannot do that, since all items in the drop down have a value. I came across a few where it is suggested that users click delete and which would set the .selectedIndex = -1 but I'd rather somehow add an empty value in the drop down that can be selected. here's what my code looks like...

I run a stored procedure and load it into DataTable which is used as my datasource...

```
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

    oCombobox.DataSource = dt
    oCombobox.ValueMember = "ID"
    oCombobox.DisplayMember = "Name"
    oCombobox.SelectedIndex = -1
```

I have done quite a bit of research and simply can't find a workable solution for VB.Net, I've come across a few solution to C# however DataTable.AddRow() is not one of the functions for VB therefore am unable to implement it in my project.

EDIT

```
 Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    dr("ID") = 0
    dr("Name") = ""
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
```

Comment: If none/nothing/null is valid for that column, shouldnt the db table used as the datasource include a "none" ? (The DataTable object in C# is the same as the one for VB)

Comment: it is, but .AddRow() does not work in Vb.Net

Comment: You may have misread whatever you got that from - there is no AddRow for C# - it would be `myDt.Rows,Add()`

Comment: I updated it (see Edit) and new row is created but it appears all the way on the bottom

Comment: `dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr,0)`  It would be easier to add a row to the DB Table

Comment: @Plutonix - this did it. if you want to post as answer else I'll accept Jinx's answer. You guys both are very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: "@Plutonix good point. That's probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add a union in my procedure with blank values:

```
SELECT ID = 0,
       Name = ''

UNION

SELECT ID,
       Name
FROM YourTable
```

You can then do an `Order By` so that 0 starts at the top. Not sure if this is the best way of doing it but it's worked for me in the past.

You could modify the `DataTable` and add a new row with blank values:

```
Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
dr("ID") = 0
dr("Name") = ""
dt.Rows.Add(dr)
```

If you want to order the `DataTable` your best bet will be to use a `DataView`:

```
Dim dv As New DataView(dt)
dv.Sort = "ID ASC"
```

Or as Plutonix has said in a comment:

`dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr,0)`

Comment: I like this, the problem is that I'm using a stored procedure - and I kind wish it could stay in the format it is already

Comment: I have admin access so I can update it, I'm trying to find a way to do it without touching it as it is used throughout the entire application.

Comment: As @Plutonix says you may have been misinformed. `Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow` followed by adding the values into `dr(0)`, `dr(1)` etc followed by `dt.Rows.Add(dr)` if you want to add a row to your `DataTable`.

Comment: I updated it (see Edit) and new row is created but it appears all the way on the bottom

Comment: Yeah I expected that. You will have use a DataView. `Dim dv As New DataView(dt)` then `dv.Sort = "ID ASC"` and assign the `DataView` to your `.DataSource`. I haven't tested but that's what I think you'll need.

Comment: Oh boy, this is the reason why I love VB6! Thank for your help @Jinx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I already try to use it and it works. :)

```
Combobox1.datasource = table
Combobox1.SelectedIndex = -1
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Column you want to display"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
```